# Extracting hashtags in several tweets using R

Tags: r

I desperately want a solution to extracting hashtags from  collective tweets in R. 
For example:

```
[[1]]
[1] "RddzAlejandra: RT @NiallOfficial: What a day for @johnJoeNevin ! Sooo proud t have been there to see him at #London2012 and here in mgar #MullingarShuffle"

[[2]]
[1] "BPOInsight: RT @atos: Atos completes delivery of key IT systems for London 2012 Olympic Games http://t.co/Modkyo2R #london2012"

[[3]]
[1] "BloombergWest: The #Olympics sets a ratings record for #NBC, with 219M viewers tuning in. http://t.co/scGzIXBp #london2012 #tech"
```

How can I parse it to extract the list of hashtag words in all the tweets.
Previous solutions display only  hashtags in the first tweet with these error messages in the code:

```
> string <-"MonicaSarkar: RT @saultracey: Sun kissed #olmpicrings at #towerbridge #london2012   @ Tower Bridge http://t.co/wgIutHUl"
> 
> [[2]]
Error: unexpected '[[' in "[["
> [1] "ccrews467: RT @BBCNews: England manager Roy Hodgson calls #London2012 a \"wake-up call\": footballers and fans should emulate spirit of #Olympics http://t.co/wLD2VA1K" 
Error: unexpected '[' in "["
> hashtag.regex <- perl("(?<=^|\\s)#\\S+")
> hashtags <- str_extract_all(string, hashtag.regex)
> print(hashtags)
[[1]]
[1] "#olmpicrings" "#towerbridge" "#london2012"
```

Comment: If you post your previous code we can probably show you where to loop or recurse to sweep out all elements of `yourdata[[1:n]][1]`

Comment: Just saying, using a vector in double square brackets will give you a  "attempt to select more than one element" error :)

Comment: Please accept an answer if it satisfactorily answers your question or explain why it doesn't in a comment to the answer.

Comment: @SachaEpskamp -- yes, I was too hasty in trying to describe the range of data the OP was presumably searching.  Sorry.

Answer (score 9):

Using `regmatches` and `gregexpr` this gives you a list with hashtags per tweet, assuming hastag is of format # followed by any number of letters or digits (I am not that familiar with twitter):

```
foo <- c("RddzAlejandra: RT @NiallOfficial: What a day for @johnJoeNevin ! Sooo proud t have been there to see him at #London2012 and here in mgar #MullingarShuffle","BPOInsight: RT @atos: Atos completes delivery of key IT systems for London 2012 Olympic Games http://t.co/Modkyo2R #london2012","BloombergWest: The #Olympics sets a ratings record for #NBC, with 219M viewers tuning in. http://t.co/scGzIXBp #london2012 #tech")

regmatches(foo,gregexpr("#(\\d|\\w)+",foo))
```

Returns:

```
[[1]]
[1] "#London2012"       "#MullingarShuffle"

[[2]]
[1] "#london2012"

[[3]]
[1] "#Olympics"   "#NBC"        "#london2012" "#tech"
```

Answer (score 3):

How about a `strsplit` and `grep` version:

```
> lapply(strsplit(x, ' '), function(w) grep('#', w, value=TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "#London2012"       "#MullingarShuffle"

[[2]]
[1] "#london2012"

[[3]]
[1] "#Olympics"   "#NBC,"       "#london2012" "#tech"
```

I couldn't figure out how to return multiple results from each string without first splitting, but I bet there is a way!