# Creating a data frame from regmatches in R

Tags: regex, r

I have hunted and hunted but cannot understand how to convert an output from regmatches into anything that can be exported. Hopefully this problem isn't so specific it is worthless to the community. I had a similar problem to the one in the following link:

[Extracting hashtags in several tweets using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959023/extracting-hashtags-in-several-tweets-using-r)

However, I cannot figure out how to save/export/make a data frame from the list made by regmatches. Ideally, each has tag would be saved in a separate column. but any time I try I get an output like:

```
[[6267]]
character(0)

[[6268]]
[1] "#ASCO15"

[[6269]]
[1] "#FDA"        "#Fast"       "#Track"      "#AML"        "#Pancreatic"
```

and if I try to export the result of the regmatches I get:

```
Error in data.frame(character(0), character(0), character(0), character(0),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 8, 2, 3, 5, 1, 4, 7, 6, 9
```

Thanks You

EDIT:
Sorry, I have may have done a poor job explaining myself.

```
dput(hi)
structure(list(text = c("Hooray ! #Wimbledon2Day has plugged its brain back in at last ! No more sub- Top Gear telly #propertenniscoverage", 
"gone but never forgotten #TopGear ", "The final episode of 'Top Gear' with Jeremy Clarkson is going to break records http://brbr.co/1JCeJYc\312"
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), .Names = "text")
```

From that data, I want to pull out the hashtags (#) and the words after them, and assign them to columns. The code from the link above does the first part of that.

```
test<-regmatches(hi$text,gregexpr("#(\\d|\\w)+",hi$text),)
```

Giving me:

```
[[1]]
[1] "#Wimbledon2Day"        "#propertenniscoverage"

[[2]]
[1] "#TopGear"

[[3]]
character(0)
```

But when I try to examine it or export it I get:

```
Error in data.frame(c("#Wimbledon2Day", "#propertenniscoverage"), "#TopGear",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 1, 0
```

Comment: what do you want the data frame to look like?  Do you want a column for every hashtag and a row for every tweet?

Comment: `dput` some data in order to create a little data and a reproducible example of the code that triggers that error.

Comment: perhaps try `rbindlist(df,fill=T)` from the `data.table` package (`1.9.5+`), which would at least give you a `data.frame`, though it may be in a very messy form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using a sparse matrix if you have large numbers of tweets and unique hashtags.  You can find one such sparse matrix object `itemMatrix` in the `arules` package.  You can coerce the list directly into this sparse matrix without having to write out the `unique` and `sapply` steps in @LegalizeIt's answer (which is a great base solution, and I give him +1).

```
foo <- c("RddzAlejandra: RT @NiallOfficial: What a day for @johnJoeNevin ! Sooo proud t have been there to see him at #London2012 and here in mgar #MullingarShuffle","BPOInsight: RT @atos: Atos completes delivery of key IT systems for London 2012 Olympic Games http://t.co/Modkyo2R #london2012","BloombergWest: The #Olympics sets a ratings record for #NBC, with 219M viewers tuning in. http://t.co/scGzIXBp #london2012 #tech")

ms <- regmatches(foo, gregexpr("#(\\d|\\w)+", foo))  # extract hashtags from tweet (from other post)

library(arules)
im <- as(ms, "itemMatrix")

#you can retrieve the rows like this
as(im,"matrix")
#   #london2012 #London2012 #MullingarShuffle #NBC #Olympics #tech
# 1           0           1                 1    0         0     0
# 2           1           0                 0    0         0     0
# 3           1           0                 0    1         1     1
```

Comment: You might also want to think about making your hashtags case-insensitive... so #london2012 and #London2012 are grouped together... perhaps `ms <- tolower(regmatches(...))`

Answer (score 1):

Using the example from the linked post,

```
foo <- c("RddzAlejandra: RT @NiallOfficial: What a day for @johnJoeNevin ! Sooo proud t have been there to see him at #London2012 and here in mgar #MullingarShuffle","BPOInsight: RT @atos: Atos completes delivery of key IT systems for London 2012 Olympic Games http://t.co/Modkyo2R #london2012","BloombergWest: The #Olympics sets a ratings record for #NBC, with 219M viewers tuning in. http://t.co/scGzIXBp #london2012 #tech")

ms <- regmatches(foo, gregexpr("#(\\d|\\w)+", foo))  # extract hashtags from tweet (from other post)
cols <- unique(unlist(ms))                           # get unique hashtags

setNames(data.frame(t(sapply(ms, function(i) cols %in% i))), cols)

#   #London2012 #MullingarShuffle #london2012 #Olympics  #NBC #tech
# 1        TRUE              TRUE       FALSE     FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 2       FALSE             FALSE        TRUE     FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 3       FALSE             FALSE        TRUE      TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

The rows correspond to the tweets.